# Request objects with ajax and process them

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to learn Ajax partial-page rendering.

So far, I managed to request a String and write it in the page. Now I'm trying to request an object, and I'm stuck.

Lets say I have this in my Ajax controller

```
MyClass obj = new MyClass();
obj.setA("Content of A");
obj.setB("Content of B");
obj.setC("Content of C");
PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
```

What would be a good way of sending instance to an ajax request?

My Ajax script looks like this:

```
function getData(){
    // .. //
    xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) {
            if (xmlHttp.status == 200) {

                document.getElementById("result").style.display='block';
                // How to handle xmlHttp response ?
            }
        }
    }
    xmlHttp.open("GET", "/index2", true);
    xmlHttp.send(null);
}
```

And in my html I should get this:

```
<div id="result" style="display:none">
    <a href="obj.A">
        obj.B
    </a>
</div>
```

I know you cannot request a MyClass instance, but I heard you can request xml or table, how could I turn my MyClass instance in a xml or table format, and how could I process it in my ajax response handler? Is there a better way then my xml ideea?

Comment: When you export object, I recommend using json format (xml is also a possibility but is much harder to process using javascript)

Comment: see this Q/A : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106778/convert-java-object-to-json-and-vice-versa

Comment: I made an answer of it in order to make it easier for someone else to find the answer on this page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you export object, I recommend using json format (xml is also a possibility but is much harder to process using javascript)

You can see this topic to learn how to convert Java object to JSON : [convert java object to json and vice versa](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18106778/convert-java-object-to-json-and-vice-versa)

Answer (score 1):

Property `responseText` contains response

```
xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function () 
{
   if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4) 
   {
      if (xmlHttp.status == 200) 
      {
          document.getElementById("result").style.display='block';
          var response = JSON.parse(xmlHttp.responseText);
         // precess response
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't really answear my question, I already knew how to get a Text. But my response isn't just a string, but an object/xml

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin you can convert string to JSON object with `JSON.parse` method. If you have XML in response, use should use `responseXml` property